# Difference Between Walking and Sitting Meditation

Tags: meditation

I wonder simply what the difference is between walking and sitting meditation in terms of value on the path. I have been practicing walking meditation for some time without any seeming result.

**Is it necessary to practice sitting meditation to see results, or for walking meditation to be truly effective? If formal sitting meditation is important, then why is that so?**

Answer (score 4):

Walking meditation is great to developp awareness in everyday life. The setting is more likely to reproduce what you will experience throughout your day.

While in sitting meditation, there are usually much less distractions occuring.

So, from my point of view of a relative beginner, sitting meditation is effective to empty your mind and experience higher levels of concentration, and walking meditation is effective to help you carry this concentration into your daily life.

Walking meditation is also very convenient when you lack energy, you will usually feel much less sleepy walking than sitting. 
In addition, if you already seat all day at work and meditate for long periods of time, alternating between sitting and walking meditation might be a good idea to maintain a healthy life style.

Answer (score 1):

Walking meditation brings weak results unless practised with empty mind of letting go. The [Cankama Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an05/an05.029.agku.html) says the samadhi developed with walking meditation is "long lasting" (*samādhi ciraṭṭhitiko*); thus of comparable worth to sitting meditation. However, for this to occur, the walking meditation must be done properly, with supramundane empty mind of letting go.

For meditators that practise common walking meditation of: "*lifting, placing, touching*, etc"; their sitting meditation is generally much better than their walking meditation because their walking meditation method is too stiff & contrived. It does not allow clear consciousness to fluidly flow.

But for those expert in empty mind, the walking meditation is seamless with sitting. A proper supramundane walker can walk very close to jhana because their samadhi is lofty; floating unhindered towards the heavens.

Comment: "The suttas teach (somewhere)..." - I'd be very interested in reading the source of this information. If you could track this down I'd be very appreciative. :-)

Comment: https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an05/an05.029.agku.html

Comment: Thank you. I notice another translation here... https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an05/an05.029.than.html

Comment: also https://suttacentral.net/an5.29/en/sujato and https://suttacentral.net/an5.29/en/bodhi

Answer (score 0):

Simple explanation for term **Meditation** is awareness on mind, basically we can Meditate at theses three position,

- Sitting
- Walking
- Lay down

> Is it necessary to practice sitting meditation to see results, or for walking meditation to be truly effective? If formal sitting meditation is important, then why is that so?

Sitting meditation is not necessary, we can do meditate our day to day life, when we are walking we can focus on our mind and walk,
when we are Sitting and do something focus on the work,
even lay down for get some rest (not sleep) we can focus on our mind. Like so we can always aware about what we are doing now, and that way we can sharp our mind, then only we can see through the everything, following the **VIDHARSHANA** meditation. Hope you could understand.